# Floodfill replace with GDI?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi

My application has a static control which inside has a tab control. It looks like this:
[alt text http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/5645/topbar.png](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/5645/topbar.png)

and I want to handle the topbar's paint event so that after it has drawn itself (and its children), have it floodfill to look more like this:

[alt text http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/9620/topbarb.png](http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/9620/topbarb.png)

Given that I'v subclassed the topbar and can override any of its events, how could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd try would be to fill it in response to [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648055(VS.85).aspx) (and I'd use [`FillRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932720.aspx), not [`FloodFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162726(VS.85).aspx)).